# Coherence using FFT: how to calculate coherence for one frame

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation, spectral-analysis

I want to calculate coherence between two time series that are of equal lengths.
Since coherence is given by

> Pxy/(sqrt(Pxx)*sqrt(Pyy))

, I did the following steps.

> Step 1: Divide both time series (say, A and B) into multiple blocks
> (block length  =2048)
>
> Step 2: Multiply each block with blackmann window and calculate FFT.
> Repeat this for both time series
>
> Step 3: For each block, calculate cross spectral density Pxy by fft(A) * conjugate(fft(B))
>
> Step 4: For each block, calculate Coherence with  the above formula.

I have 2 problems when implementing the above algorithm

> 1. coherence comes out as  1 for all frequencies.
>
> How to get a coherence spectrogram, where I can compare the coherence
> of each frequency at different points of time ?
>
> 2. The imaginary part of Pxy is always 0. I am not even sure if this is an error or not.

Comment: Formulas and steps sound right to me.

Since coherence = 1 for all frequencies my first suggestion would be to make sure that there isn't something somewhere that makes x = y.

Another check is to compare one (or both) of the auto-spectra to the cross-spectrum. If they're equal, that's an indication that x = y as well.

What language are you using? There are functions in MATLAB, R (multitaper package for example), and (I assume) Python to calculate the coherence.

Lastly, try using the straight FFTs; no blackmann window for now just to see if something went sideways in its calculation.

Comment: The functions in those languages don't give me a spectrogram. Just one single vector of coherence for the whole length of data.That's not enough for me.

Comment: To get coherence (or spectrum) as a function of time i.e., by block, you could calculate the coherence for each block and store it them as columns of a matrix. Plot the matrix as a heatmap. In R, you could use something like fields::image.plot(x=blockNumVec, y = frequency, z = t(cohgram)) .  I can't quite remember why the transpose is needed right now on the z-component, but, whether it's there or not, that would be the idea. If you're implementing the coherence from scratch you would have to deal with this anyway? I thought the main issue was coh=1 and Im(coh) = 0 .

Comment: I am trying to do coherence from scratch. My problem is not with the plotting. Even if I manually break the data into blocks and call these functions for each block, the coherence still comes out as  1 for all frequency in every block regardless of whether I am using in-built library functions of if I am implementing the formula given there.  Thats my problem. Is coherence supposed to be calculated for each block ?

Comment: Yes, you would calculate the coherence for each block of data. A couple more suggestions: A) generate two white-noise series; one for x and one for y, then run your coherence code (single block). Are you still getting coherence = 1 at all frequencies? B) Are you able to share the data (or a piece of it) or simulation, etc.. where you are getting coherence = 1? It *sounds* to me like the data is the reason behind coh=1 if you're getting the same output from your code and in-built library functions, but A) would be a quick check. I wish I could be more helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instantaneous coherence function for a single pair of FFT frames is always equal to one. In the numerator, you are multiplying complex spectrum X with the complex conjugate of spectrum Y and then squaring the result. In the denominator you end up taking the sum of the squares of the real and imaginary parts of spectrum X and spectrum Y.

The conjugate of a complex number works out to keeping the real part and and inverting the sign of the imaginary part. The sign change in the imaginary part falls out when you square the numbers. So, for any single X and Y pair, the numerator and the denominator are expected to be identical, addition and multiplication being commutative.

In a perfectly noiseless LTI system you would further expect the relationship between the input and output spectra to remain constant when averaged over time. I real world systems, X and Y will tend to diverge when averaged across multiple frames, resulting in coherence of less than one.